# Windows 10 file explorer continually crashes

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, taskbar

I upgraded to Windows 10 recently and the biggest issue I'm having is that every time I click on file explorer (whether from the start menu or the taskbar), the file explorer AND taskbar crashes. I also cannot right-click a file in the file explorer nor can I extract .zip files without the crashes.

I've seen a few updates that have worked for other users, but unfortunately, they're not working for me.

Comment: capture a crash dump and share the zip of the dump: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: have you captured a crash dump?

Comment: Try checking the free space on your hard drive. I have a similar problem on Windows 7, and the cause is probably the small amount of space left on my computer.